# Toyota Corolla with hot wheels

Tags: toyota, brakes, wheels

I have been having hot wheels of recent since I changed the brake pads. After like 2km drive it will be excessively hot.I have had the calipers serviced and even changed the masters,yet it persisted. Am kind of worried over this. What do you suggest?

Comment: Typically this is caused by the brake pads rubbing against the rotor, if the calipers and master cylinder are both working properly then the only answer would be the pads are too thick. Are you sure you got the right pads?

Comment: Is that 2km drive with no braking?

Comment: A defective brake hose could also cause this.